# A way to create a number sequence generator?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to make a function or stored procedure which will generate a sequence of numbers - 1,2,3.... It should be able to remember the number it had generated when it was last called. For example, I just make it and then call it 10 times. Last gen = 10. I stop DB and close the computer. The next time I run this function, it should generate 11.

Can someone suggest how I can do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done for now? what are the problems you are facing, or how are you thinking of doing it, just post something more, so we can haid you..

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to at least demonstrate some knowledge of the question you are asking.

Comment: @logixologist - I am new to SQL In this case, I am not able to figure out any code. I just need some tips to get started and figure it out on my own.

Comment: I don't know why I am being down voted for this ?

Comment: Ok fare enough... looks up a site called w3schools, they are a good tutorial for .net and SQL as a start. Once you have some basic understanding of SQL, then look up Identity. What you are asking for already exists by adding an identity column to your table. Any time something is inserted it increases it by 1.

Comment: See the top item on the [ask] page.

Comment: The downvotes are from people who are upset that you are asking a question for what you have no knowledge of. Its always best to look it up, try to come up with some code and you can always post it saying that you are having trouble with it. It shows initiative and not just asking for free code. Just google what you are looking for and its all out their. And if you get stuck there are SQL gurus on SO that can easily point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like Steve Fenton has explained Identity Column is the way to go for this kind of requirement but if you do need to Create sequential number you will need to do two things

> 1- Create a table which will keep record of all the created sequential Numbers for you as store procedure cannot do this for you.
>   2- create a Stored Procedure for that table, to generate numbers for you something like this...

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Number (Nums INT)
GO
```

**Store Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NumberGenerator
@NumberOfNumber INT
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @MaxNum INT
   DECLARE @Inc INT
   SELECT @MaxNum = MAX(Nums) FROM Number

   IF (@MaxNum IS NULL)
   BEGIN
     SET @MaxNum = 0
   END

   SET @Inc = 1

   WHILE (@NumberOfNumber > 0)
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Number (Nums)
      VALUES (@MaxNum + @Inc)

       SET @Inc = @Inc +1
       SET @NumberOfNumber = @NumberOfNumber -1
    END

    SELECT Nums FROM Number 
    WHERE Nums > @MaxNum 
END
```

**Retrieve Generated Values**

```
CREATE TABLE #table (Number INT)

INSERT INTO #table (Number) 
EXECUTE NumberGenerator @NumberOfNumber = ??? --<-- Number of values you want to generate

SELECT * FROM #table
```

Comment: I get an error when I execute it as exec NumberGenerator '20'. Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure NumberGenerator, Line 13
Invalid object name 'Numbers'.

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT try now I had an extra 's' with my table name in insert statement, and accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT You are passing a string when you pass the parameter like '20', it takes INT parameter, pass the value without single quotes.

Comment: Thanks. The retrieve gen values code causes the error -Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure NumberGenerator, Line 0
Error converting data type nvarchar to int. How do i fix this ?

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT Sorry I didnt test it myself before now its working fine just make sure you truncate you Number table before you execute this, I have Altered the store procedure's Definition as well please have a look now.

Comment: Thanks. that works. I had seen a stored procedure somewhere that just returns one row with a number. wonder where that was.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the ideal use of a SQL identity column, which by default auto-increments by one each time you add a row. If you are thinking of using your function to generate Id numbers for your rows, you should look at identity columns.

If you really need a number generator, you could store a single row in a sequence table, and within a transaction read it, increment it and save it back.

Comment: This sounds like a horrid use of an (SQL Server) identity column. Identity columns are not dense sequences. (The question has been written somewhat generally without reference to PK usage: "I need to make a function or stored procedure which will generate a sequence of numbers".)

Comment: I think you misunderstand - my suggestion was if the number is being generated to use as an Id, use an identity column. The second sentence describes how you would store the number in a table to persist the last value and manually increment the sequence and return it.

Comment: @SteveFenton too bad you cant down vote comments. You had a perfectly legitimate answer for a very poorly asked question.

Comment: @logixologist thanks - I like to read between the lines and try and answer the root question, rather than just taking things at face value.

Comment: Yeah I think many times SO users tend to be so worried about disqualifying a question. Some questions, despite poorly written are legitimate problems that just may not have clearly stated them. I try to use my advice whenver I can to get people in the right direction.

Comment: @logixologist I don't see how it's so poorly worded: "I need to make a function or stored procedure which will generate a sequence of numbers." Seems like a perfectly legitimate question. While it is important to address Y, where appropriate, one shouldn't so completely disqualify X, especially when there was an "X" asked for in not-so-unclear terms. As far the dig about downvoting comments, I think that was uncalled for.